# Update only the fields sent in a JSON

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this piece of code:

```
// Update a card    
router.patch('/:id', async (req, res) => {    
    try {    
        const card = await Card.findByIdAndUpdate(        
            {_id: req.params.id},    
            { $set: {    
                title: req.body.title,    
                description: req.body.description}},    
            { new: true });    
        res.json(card);    
    } catch (error) {    
        res.status(404).json({message: error});    
    }    
});
```

I want to be able to update the title and the description individually, meaning if I send a JSON containing only the title, then only the title will be updated, the problem is that if I do this with the code above, because description is missing then description will be updated to null. Is there a way to update only what I send in the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I used this piece of code to solve the problem:

```
const $set = {};
    if(req.body.name)
        $set.name = req.body.name;
    if(req.body.background)
        $set.background = req.body.background;
    const board = await Board.findByIdAndUpdate(
        {_id: req.params.id},
        { $set },
        { new: true });
```